# Discord.js Member Count reduces issue

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am developing a bot for counting the Members in the server in my Discord server. Now I have 270 total members. But for the Member Count, it reaches to 199 Members and then it automatically drops to 160 Members. I don't know what's happening as it just randomly reduces from 199 to 160 or 168 members. It doesn't reach 200. When I first added the bot I didn't have any issues. Only recently its been doing this. The code is below.

```js
const {
  config
} = require("dotenv");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();


// Variables
const ownerID = '426345341072179223';

const PREFIX = '.';

// Message to ping the bot
client.on('message', message => {

  let args =
    message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'ping':
      message.reply('you have successfuly pinged me');
      break;

  }

})

client.once("ready", () => {
  //When bot is ready
  client.user.setActivity(`SpongeBoZZ ACAB on 
          YouTube`, {
    type: 'LISTENING'
  }); //It will set status 
  : )
});

// Server Stats Setup
const serverStats = {
  guildID: '669622560098353152',
  totalUsersID: '694688882977144854',
  memberCountID: '694689022588616814',
  botCountID: '694689099725930597'
};


client.on('ready', () => console.log('Bot is now 
      Connected '));

      client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

          if (member.guild.id !== serverStats.guildID)
            return;


          ` client.channels.cache.get(serverStats.totalUsersID).setName(`
          Total Users: $ {
            member.guild.memberCount
          }
          `);
    client.channels.cache.get(serverStats.memberCountID).setName(`
          Member Count: $ {
            member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => !m.user.bot).size
          }
          `);
    client.channels.cache.get(serverStats.botCountID).setName(`
          Bot Count: $ {
            member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.user.bot).size
          }
          `);

});

client.on('guildMemberRemove', member =>
{

    if (member.guild.id !== serverStats.guildID) return;

    client.channels.cache.get(serverStats.totalUsersID).setName(`
          Total Users: $ {
            member.guild.memberCount
          }
          `);
    client.channels.cache.get(serverStats.memberCountID).setName(`
          Member Count: $ {
            member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => !m.user.bot).size
          }
          `);
    client.channels.cache.get(serverStats.botCountID).setName(`
          Bot Count: $ {
            member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.user.bot).size
          }
          `);

});



// Login to Discord
client.login(process.env.token);
```

Answer (score 0):

For "Total Users", you're using `.memberCount` which is direct from the Discord API. For "Member Count" and "Bot Count", you're pulling the numbers directly from cache. Here, it isn't guaranteed that every member/user will be cached, which will affect the accuracy of your counts.

Answer (score -1):

to count the member of user present on all discord server your bot is, you can do something like:

```
let membersCount = 0;
client.users.cache.map(users => users.id ? membersCount += 1 : false).pop()
console.log(membersCount);
```

Then you get the amount of users you bot can see!

to get the nb of members on a single guild you have yo change the client user by the guild collection.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {

let membersCount = 0;
message.guild.members.cache.map(users => users.id ? membersCount += 1 : false).pop()
console.log(membersCount);
});
```

Comment: That will give an error and say users.id ? Is not defined

Comment: Ok so to clarify where in the code is the above to be entered. My bot is in one server.

Comment: i'm not sure to understant

Comment: Can you rewrite the code with your part added so i know where it needs to go in the code. I am not sure where to put it.

Comment: you just need to copy and past in your index.js

Comment: So everything stays where it is just i add this part of code into it and it will work?

Comment: what's your full error ??????????????
you just need to copy past my code where a variable client is.

Comment: **That didnt work. it shows on the console log 141 members but on the discord it is showing as 124 Members.**

Comment: ? i told you that the first bit of code shows all users that the bot can see, which means the sum of all members on all discord server the bot is on. The second bit of code represent the total amount of users on the server where the message has been send and it does not count bots in the final number

Comment: *ok but this doesn't solve my issue. The issue i am having is directly on Discord where the member count is a voice channel and it updates when someone joins and leaves the server. The issue there is the voice channel reaches 200 members then auto drops the numbers down. So for some reason the bot is not adding the members when it reaches 200 members. This is the issue i am trying to solve.*

Comment: yes i did i followed youtube videos and discord.js doc